# iterate through images

Tags: java, android

I have 100 images, each is an image of a percentage, for example, 1%, 2%, 3%, etc.

What's the best way to go through each image?  Should I add each image resource to a List or Dictionary(if that exists in Android).  Or am I forced to hard code it?

```
public void ShowCircle(final int percentage){
    final ImageView ring = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ring);
    ring.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                for(int i = 0; i != percentage; i++)

                            //I was thinking here I can access list/dictionary records.
                ring.setImageResource(R.drawable.percent_1);
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: Have a look at [How do I iterate through the id properties of R.java class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941459/how-do-i-iterate-through-the-id-properties-of-r-java-class) and [Programatically iterate through Resource ids](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3545196/android-programatically-iterate-through-resource-ids).

Comment: @MattBall - Thanks, the 'How do I iterate through the id properties of R.java class?' had the answer I was looking for.

Comment: I used the the following resource as MattBall suggested.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941459/how-do-i-iterate-through-the-id-properties-of-r-java-class

Comment: @MattBall - Can you please post as an answer, so I can mark it as correct for now?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At OP's request, answering with a copypasta from a comment:

> Have a look at [How do I iterate through the id properties of R.java class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941459/how-do-i-iterate-through-the-id-properties-of-r-java-class) and [Android: Programatically iterate through Resource ids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3545196/android-programatically-iterate-through-resource-ids).

...though this question should really just be closed as a dup.

Answer (score 1):

You can put them in an array (info on how to add to an array is found [here](http://www.java-forums.org/new-java/6719-how-do-i-create-array-images.html)) and then iterate trhough them with an foreach loop like so:

```
for(ImageView image : ImageArray) {
    // Do stuff with your image that is now in the variable called image. 
    // All images will be called in the order that they are positioned in the array
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would put them into an array like this

```
public static int[] picArray = new int[100];
picArray[0] = R.raw.img1;
picArray[1] = R.raw.img2;
//etc
```

and iterate through them like this

```
public void onClick(View view) 
{

    ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    if(counter== (picArray.length - 1) )
    {
        counter =0;


    }
    else
    {
        counter++;

    }
    image.setImageResource(picArray[counter].getImg());

}
```